# Embedded loops containing SQL connections

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
SqlConnection connection1, connection2;
SqlCommand command1, command2;
SqlDataReader reader1, reader2;

using (connection1 = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
{

    using (command1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [SERVER1].[DATABASE1].[TABLE1] WHERE COL1 = @COL1 AND COL2 = @COL2", connection1))
    {

        command1.Parameters.Add("@COL1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        command1.Parameters.Add("@COL2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox2.Text;

        connection1.Open();
        using (reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (reader1.Read())
            {

                int COL3Index = reader1.GetOrdinal("COL3");

                Console.Write("### LOOP 1 ###");
                Console.Write(reader1.GetDouble(COL3Index));

                using (connection2 = new SqlConnection("same connection string here"))
                {

                    using (command2 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [SERVER1].[DATABASE1].[TABLE2] WHERE COL1 = @COL1", connection1))
                    {

                        command2.Parameters.Add("@COL1", SqlDbType.Float).Value = reader1.GetDouble(COL3Index);

                        connection2.Open();
                        using (reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader())
                        {

                            while (reader2.Read())
                            {

                                int COL2Index = reader2.GetOrdinal("COL2");

                                Console.Write("### LOOP 2 ###");
                                Console.Write(reader2.GetDouble(COL2Index));

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Basically 2 of everything, I will be needing to do this 5 times, i.e. loop within loop within loop within loop within loop...

The first loop on its own works, but the second one does not work and gives the following error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

on the line:

```
using (reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader())
```

How can I get this to work as I need to embed loops

Comment: Check line where you create `command2`. It's tied to `connection1` (see last `SqlCommand` constructor parameter). Oh BTW I'd refactor that method...

Comment: Does your connection string allow for multiple open datasets?  Take a look at this MSDN article: [Multiple Active Result Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Also, you really don't need two connections here to perform two queries.  LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities may be something to look into (or any other ORM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the definition of [Select N+1](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn/alert/selectnplusone) and should be avoided if possible. I would recommend using something like Entity Framework and [eagerly loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) the child values.

If not possible to avoid, loop though your entire reader1 results, assign to a local collection, close reader1, and then iterate through the local collection and load based on the local values.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid action (to loop through DataReader) if he uses all columns (otherwise he just need to narrow its query in SELECT command). To load list in memory is pretty dangerous. 10 records? 1,000 records? 1,000,000 records? That said that code is pretty inefficient (and **error is he's creating command2 into connection1**) but **solution is to use a JOIN**. One connection, one query.

Answer (score 0):

You have no reason to open the connection twice if you have [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28VS.80%29.aspx) enabled to the same database/connection string.  This can be done by adding `"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"` to your connection string.

Additionally, You can use a [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load the data into a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then query the DataSet.  However, this assumes that your tables aren't too big that you can load them into memory, otherwise an ORM would be a better option.

An ORM solution such as LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities via Entity Framework (as mentioned in Mike Cole's answer) could really help you out here so you don't need to worry about writing these queries and handling the connections.  Instead you just rely on a DataContext to handle the connections.